# Why does passing in an array of 4 values in props, setting exactly in data, result in the array in data having 5 values?

Tags: vue.js

I created a component `TablePickOne`. This is working just fine with one table, but the problem comes when I want to alternate between tables.

In the root vue file, I have:

```
<TablePickOne v-if="classChart==0" v-bind:tableActiveId="chosenId" v-bind:tableHeaders="generalChartHeaders" v-bind:tableRows="choices" v-on:select-item="selectClass"/>

<TablePickOne v-if="classChart==1" v-bind:tableActiveId="chosenId" v-bind:tableHeaders="specialtiesChartHeaders" v-bind:tableRows="choices" v-on:select-item="selectClass"/>
```

I also have a chart for when `classChart == 2 or 3`. I just created TablePickOne, so I'm trying to move them all over, but 2 and 3 are just  elements right now.

In my TablePickOne.vue file, I have:

```
export default {
    name: 'TablePickOne',
    props: {
        'tableActiveId': Number,
        'tableHeaders': Array,
        'tableRows': Array
    },
    data() {
        return {
            selectedId: this.tableActiveId,
            headers: this.tableHeaders,
            rows: this.tableRows
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Cases:**

- If am showing chart 0, and click chart 1 button, it keeps showing chart 0. **Wrong** When looking at the Vue DevTools, TablePickOne has props with tableHeaders: Array[4] and data with headers: Array[5]
- If am showing chart 1, and click chart 0 button, it keeps showing chart 1 **Wrong** When looking at the Vue DevTools, TablePickOne has props with tableHeaders: Array[5] and data with headers: Array[4]
- If am showing chart 2 or 3, and click chart 1 button, it changes to show chart 1. **Right**
- If am showing chart 2 or 3, and click chart 0 button, it changes to show chart 0. **Right**
- If am showing chart 0/1, and click chart 2/3 button, it changes to show the correct chart (2/3). **Right**

Comment: Why are you copying the prop values to `data`? Without knowing your motivation for that it's difficult to suggest an appropriate fix. The copying will only occur once, when the component is created.  When `classChart` changes it will reuse the existing `TablePickOne` component, just passing in the new prop values. That won't update the `data`. If you want to force the creation of new components each time use a different `key` on each component.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! (I set a different key on each component to force it to create new components)